# CMake and Magick++ - undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, magick++

I'm trying to create a simple image converter using CLion and Magick++ 7. 
I've installed the Magick++ with the official guide and "identify -version" shows ImageMagick 7.0.7-25.
However, when I try to use Magick::ReadOptions and Magick::Image::quality I get a reference error:

> undefined reference to 'Magick::ReadOptions::ReadOptions()'
>   undefined reference to 'Magick::ReadOptions::quiet(bool)'
>   undefined reference to 'Magick::Image::quality(unsigned long)'
>   undefined reference to 'Magick::ReadOptions::~ReadOptions()'
>   undefined reference to 'Magick::ReadOptions::~ReadOptions()'

Here's my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(zosia_konwerter)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(zosia_konwerter main.cpp)

add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )

find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED COMPONENTS Magick++ MagickWand MagickCore)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(zosia_konwerter ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})

find_package(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) # enable dynamic linking
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)  # enable multithreading
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS REQUIRED chrono filesystem)
target_link_libraries (zosia_konwerter ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The code in c++ is pretty straightforward:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <string>
std::string src="src/", res="res/";
int main(int argc,char **argv) {

    Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Magick::ReadOptions options;
    options.quiet(true);
    Magick::Image image;
    for(auto &p : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(src)) {
            image.read(p.path().string());
            image.resize("800x800>");
            image.quality(85);
            image.write(res+p.path().stem().string()+".jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which OS do you use (Windows, Linux)? Version of ImageMagick detected by CMake can be obtained from *ImageMagick_VERSION_STRING* cache variable (after `find_package(ImageMagick)` has been completed). You may grep `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory for that variable.

Comment: I'm using linux. ImageMagick_VERSION_STRING was not found, however I found the following line in CMakeCache:PC_Magick++_VERSION:INTERNAL=7.0.7

Comment: I think `Magick::ReadOptions` is a class used to transport properties between STL functions, not intended for direct access in the user-space. Use `Magick::Image.quiet(bool)` instead.